# WHy is my inline div not taking up the given space?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/fm4Xk/)

I'm trying to make my div to the right use the entire width and height of the parent div.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the HTML

```
<div style="width:150px;padding:0;min-height:200px;">
  <div style="width:100%;background-color:#99CD4E;">
    <div style="width:35px;padding:5px;display:inline-block;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
      <img src="/photos/files/5/main/small_thumb.jpg" class="thumb_small "/>    
    </div>
  <div style="height:100%;display:inline-block;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">user <strong>age</strong><br>town, state</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because of the `display:inline-block;` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of styling them with `display:inline-block` you could style the divs with `display:table-cell` and give that particular div a width of 100%.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fm4Xk/2/)**

```
<div style="width:150px;padding:0;min-height:200px;">
  <div style="width:100%;background-color:#99CD4E;">
    <div style="width:35px;padding:5px;display:table-cell;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
      <img src="/photos/files/5/main/small_thumb.jpg" class="thumb_small "/>    
    </div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:100%;display:table-cell;border: solid 1px #ff0000;">user <strong>age</strong><br>town, state</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never used table-cell before. Can I align the text to the top ?

Comment: Sure, just add `vertical-align:middle`.